# Deeply nested html_options in a link_to without using strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Is it possible to have deeply nested `html_options` with a `link_to` tag.
I want a link with bootstrap tooltip on hover.

In HAML, I can write:

```
%a{data: {bs: {toggle: "tooltip", placement: "top"}}, title: "baz", href: "bar"} foo
```

Which will output

```
<a data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="baz" href="bar">foo</a>
```

But I'd prefer to use the rails helpers if possible, so:

```
= link_to "foo", "bar", {data: {bs: {toggle: "tooltip", placement: "top"}}, title: "baz"}
```

which generates

```
<a data-bs="{"toggle":"tooltip","placement":"top"}" title="baz" href="bar">foo</a>
```

So toggle and placement aren't being separated into their own tag option.

Looking through Rails on GitHub, I can see the relevant part which generates the tag options

[`link_to`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8015c2c2cf5c8718449677570f372ceb01318a32/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L209) calls [`content_tag`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8015c2c2cf5c8718449677570f372ceb01318a32/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L368), `content_tag` calls [`content_tag_string`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8015c2c2cf5c8718449677570f372ceb01318a32/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L80), `content_tag_string` calls [`tag_options`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8015c2c2cf5c8718449677570f372ceb01318a32/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L91) which is what generates the tag options from the hash that I provide.

`tag_options` will iterate through the hash and check if the value is another hash or a string, if its a string, it places it in the tag options, if it is a hash, it will iterate through that hash to generate more tag options. However it doesn't check any deeper than 1 hash.

So now I come to my question, without modifying rails, is there any way I can use the rails `link_to` helper while having a hash within a hash, or will I have to do something like this?

```
= link_to "foo", "bar", {data: {"bs-toggle": "tooltip", "bs-placement": "top"}}, title: "baz"}
```

Which does work, but I'd prefer to use symbols if I can for cleanliness.

Comment: Short answer: If you don't want to override `link_to`,  you can only hash 1 level deep. You could add your own method in `ApplicationHelper` to turn your deep hash into a shallow hash for `link_to`, but that's only a step away from just overriding `link_to` anyway.

Comment: Thought that was going to be the case. Thanks for your help.